# Cannot replace a row in sqlite but I can insert it

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to replace the current date to a table in sqlite3. I can insert it but if I try to replace it, this error shows up: TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given).

```
maclist = get_dict.get('maclist')
signallist = get_dict.get('signallist')
data_list = list(zip(maclist, signallist))

conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
c = conn.cursor()
if (id == 1):
    try:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO node2 (MAC,SIGNAL,FECHA) VALUES(?,?,?)", data_list, datetime.now())
    except Exception as exc:
        c.executemany("REPLACE INTO node2 (MAC,SIGNAL,FECHA) VALUES(?,?,?)", data_list, datetime.now())
```

Comment: You only need the `REPLACE` sentence, not the `INSERT`

Answer (score 1):

the correct usage is

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table(column_list)
VALUES(value_list)
```

the INSERT OR REPLACE would insert if the row does not exist, or replace the values if it does.

Comment: It only works for me if I simply do that in the try statement which is weird. If I remove the except it doesn't work.

Comment: Or just `REPLACE`

Comment: @tonypdmtr It has to be both because the registry may not exist

Comment: @Alvaromr7 "The `REPLACE` command in SQLite is an alias for `INSERT OR REPLACE` variant of the `INSERT` command"

Comment: @tonypdmtr when I change anything I get this error: TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given). It only works if I leave INSERT OR REPLACE in the try statement

Comment: @Alvaromr7 Irrelevant.  `REPLACE` is the ***same*** as typing `INSERT OR REPLACE`.  Now, if leaving `except` works as you say in your first comment here, then this should also work: `if (id == 1): c.executemany("REPLACE INTO node2 (MAC,SIGNAL,FECHA) VALUES(?,?,?)", data_list, datetime.now())` without any `try ... except`

Comment: Can you post a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem?